# Two-fingered swiping is in wrong direction for webpages

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, macos, trackpad

I have just bought a new Macbook Pro with the Sierra OS. What I have found is that using the trackpad to move "back" and "forwards" between webpages, goes in the opposite direction to what I would expect.

For example, let's say I visit webpage A, then webpage B, and then webpage C. I now want to navigate back to A, and so my natural instinct would be to swipe two fingers on the trackpad from right to left. However, it seems that doing this actually moves the webpages forwards. So, in order to navigate back to A, I actually need to swipe my two fingers from left to right.

This seems odd that it would be the default, because it feels much more natural that swiping to the right is forwards, and swiping to the left is backwards.

Is this really the default setting? And if so, is there any way I can change it to the opposite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default and it actually makes sense if you consider the visual metaphor of moving between pages in a book, magazine, or newspaper.  To back from C --> A in a book you swipe the pages from left to right.  If you grab a page and move it from the right to the left, you're moving forward thru the book.

It's the same with the trackpad.  You can change this in `Settings --> Trackpad`.  If you use any other Apple product, they all use the same direction for moving between pages.

Comment: Do you see the arrows that appear when you start a swipe gesture?  Is it really natural to move your hand in the OPPOSITE direction of the arrows?  Do you really think when you see a sign pointing to the left, to move to the right?  Please let me know if you're driving in my town so I'll know to stay off the road.  You are bending over backwards to believe in anything Apple does, even when it's patently obvious that they got it wrong.

Comment: @SMBiggs Thanks for the feedback.  I was answering the questions asked by the OP as to 'why' and 'how' to change the default.  Your complaint is with Apple and not me.  Please feel free to add your own answer and the community here will assess accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help if you think of the swiping as if you were moving the current page out of the way to get to the page you want. In your example - you are trying to get back to page A from C. Imagine them in a line, oldest to the left, newest to the right. You are pushing the current page, C to the right, by swiping in a left to right movement to get to page B and then A.

Hope that helps!